# ERROR: Exit status 1, PySimpleGui - new to python

Tags: python, anaconda, pysimplegui

I am new to Python and trying to use PySimpleGUI (https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/) but haven't been able to get that far because I get errors when installing the dependencies. Perhaps this is because I am new to python and I do not have the necessary dependencies to even be running this at this point. The error is likely happening before even getting to the point of PySimpleGUI from what I can tell.

Thank you for any help, I appreciate any ideas!

---

---

```
Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 12:59:45) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.22.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

runfile('/Users/MJF/AAT-master/InstallDependencies.py', wdir='/Users/MJF/AAT-master')
Collecting astroid==2.2.5
  Using cached astroid-2.2.5-py3-none-any.whl (193 kB)
Collecting certifi==2020.6.20
  Using cached certifi-2020.6.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler==0.10.0 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (0.10.0)
Collecting isort==4.3.20
  Using cached isort-4.3.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting kiwisolver==1.2.0
  Using cached kiwisolver-1.2.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (60 kB)
Collecting lazy-object-proxy==1.4.1
  Using cached lazy_object_proxy-1.4.1-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
Collecting matplotlib==3.1.3
  Using cached matplotlib-3.1.3-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (13.2 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: mccabe==0.6.1 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 8)) (0.6.1)
Collecting numpy==1.18.1
  Using cached numpy-1.18.1-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (15.2 MB)
Collecting pandas==1.0.3
  Using cached pandas-1.0.3-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (10.2 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: patsy==0.5.1 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 11)) (0.5.1)
Collecting pylint==2.3.1
  Using cached pylint-2.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (765 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing==2.4.7 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 13)) (2.4.7)
Collecting PySimpleGUI==4.22.0
  Using cached PySimpleGUI-4.22.0-py3-none-any.whl (292 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil==2.8.1 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 15)) (2.8.1)
Collecting pytz==2020.1
  Using cached pytz-2020.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
Collecting scipy==1.4.1
  Using cached scipy-1.4.1-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (28.8 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: six==1.15.0 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 18)) (1.15.0)
Collecting statsmodels==0.11.1
  Using cached statsmodels-0.11.1-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_13_x86_64.whl (8.5 MB)
Collecting tqdm==4.42.1
  Using cached tqdm-4.42.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
Collecting typed-ast==1.3.5
  Using cached typed-ast-1.3.5.tar.gz (205 kB)
Collecting wincertstore==0.2
  Using cached wincertstore-0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.8 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt==1.11.1 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 23)) (1.11.1)
Collecting XlsxWriter==1.2.9
  Using cached XlsxWriter-1.2.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (141 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: typed-ast
  Building wheel for typed-ast (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for typed-ast (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for typed-ast
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/nn/vspv48993vsg4vx8lyb7cccr0000gn/T/pip-install-rs4sv9b3/typed-ast_fc1729a54d824752a576842638a11041/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/nn/vspv48993vsg4vx8lyb7cccr0000gn/T/pip-install-rs4sv9b3/typed-ast_fc1729a54d824752a576842638a11041/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/nn/vspv48993vsg4vx8lyb7cccr0000gn/T/pip-wheel-glvejyui
       cwd: /private/var/folders/nn/vspv48993vsg4vx8lyb7cccr0000gn/T/pip-install-rs4sv9b3/typed-ast_fc1729a54d824752a576842638a11041/
  Complete output (58 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/typed_ast
  copying typed_ast/conversions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/typed_ast
  copying typed_ast/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/typed_ast
  copying typed_ast/ast3.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/typed_ast
  copying typed_ast/ast27.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/typed_ast
  package init file 'ast3/tests/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/typed_ast/tests
  copying ast3/tests/test_basics.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/typed_ast/tests
  running build_ext
  building '_ast27' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Custom
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Parser/acceler.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/acceler.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Parser/bitset.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/bitset.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Parser/grammar.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/grammar.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Parser/grammar1.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/grammar1.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Parser/node.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/node.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Parser/parser.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/parser.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Parser/parsetok.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/parsetok.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Parser/tokenizer.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/tokenizer.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Python/asdl.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/asdl.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Python/ast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/ast.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Python/graminit.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/graminit.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Python/mystrtoul.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/mystrtoul.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Python/Python-ast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/Python-ast.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Custom/typed_ast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Custom/typed_ast.o
  gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/opt/anaconda3/lib -arch x86_64 -L/opt/anaconda3/lib -arch x86_64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/acceler.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/bitset.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/grammar.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/grammar1.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/node.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/parser.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/parsetok.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/tokenizer.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/asdl.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/ast.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/graminit.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/mystrtoul.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/Python-ast.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Custom/typed_ast.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/typed_ast/_ast27.cpython-38-darwin.so
  building '_ast3' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Python
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Custom
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast3/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Parser/acceler.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser/acceler.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast3/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Parser/bitset.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser/bitset.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast3/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Parser/grammar.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser/grammar.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast3/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Parser/grammar1.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser/grammar1.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast3/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Parser/node.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser/node.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast3/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Parser/parser.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser/parser.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast3/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Parser/parsetok.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser/parsetok.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast3/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Parser/tokenizer.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser/tokenizer.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast3/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Python/asdl.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Python/asdl.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast3/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Python/ast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Python/ast.o
  ast3/Python/ast.c:22:1: error: conflicting types for '_PyObject_FastCall'
  _PyObject_FastCall(PyObject *func, PyObject *const *args, int nargs)
  ^
  /opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/cpython/abstract.h:145:1: note: previous definition is here
  _PyObject_FastCall(PyObject *func, PyObject *const *args, Py_ssize_t nargs)
  ^
  1 error generated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for typed-ast
Failed to build typed-ast
Installing collected packages: typed-ast, pytz, numpy, lazy-object-proxy, scipy, pandas, kiwisolver, isort, astroid, XlsxWriter, wincertstore, tqdm, statsmodels, PySimpleGUI, pylint, matplotlib, certifi
  Attempting uninstall: typed-ast
    Found existing installation: typed-ast 1.4.2
    Uninstalling typed-ast-1.4.2:
      Successfully uninstalled typed-ast-1.4.2
    Running setup.py install for typed-ast: started
    Running setup.py install for typed-ast: finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/nn/vspv48993vsg4vx8lyb7cccr0000gn/T/pip-install-rs4sv9b3/typed-ast_fc1729a54d824752a576842638a11041/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/nn/vspv48993vsg4vx8lyb7cccr0000gn/T/pip-install-rs4sv9b3/typed-ast_fc1729a54d824752a576842638a11041/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/nn/vspv48993vsg4vx8lyb7cccr0000gn/T/pip-record-uyxwayne/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/typed-ast
         cwd: /private/var/folders/nn/vspv48993vsg4vx8lyb7cccr0000gn/T/pip-install-rs4sv9b3/typed-ast_fc1729a54d824752a576842638a11041/
    Complete output (58 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/typed_ast
    copying typed_ast/conversions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/typed_ast
    copying typed_ast/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/typed_ast
    copying typed_ast/ast3.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/typed_ast
    copying typed_ast/ast27.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/typed_ast
    package init file 'ast3/tests/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/typed_ast/tests
    copying ast3/tests/test_basics.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/typed_ast/tests
    running build_ext
    building '_ast27' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Custom
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Parser/acceler.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/acceler.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Parser/bitset.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/bitset.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Parser/grammar.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/grammar.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Parser/grammar1.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/grammar1.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Parser/node.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/node.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Parser/parser.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/parser.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Parser/parsetok.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/parsetok.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Parser/tokenizer.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/tokenizer.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Python/asdl.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/asdl.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Python/ast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/ast.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Python/graminit.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/graminit.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Python/mystrtoul.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/mystrtoul.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Python/Python-ast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/Python-ast.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast27/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Custom/typed_ast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Custom/typed_ast.o
    gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/opt/anaconda3/lib -arch x86_64 -L/opt/anaconda3/lib -arch x86_64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/acceler.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/bitset.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/grammar.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/grammar1.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/node.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/parser.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/parsetok.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/tokenizer.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/asdl.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/ast.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/graminit.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/mystrtoul.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/Python-ast.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Custom/typed_ast.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/typed_ast/_ast27.cpython-38-darwin.so
    building '_ast3' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Python
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Custom
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast3/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Parser/acceler.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser/acceler.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast3/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Parser/bitset.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser/bitset.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast3/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Parser/grammar.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser/grammar.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast3/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Parser/grammar1.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser/grammar1.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast3/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Parser/node.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser/node.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast3/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Parser/parser.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser/parser.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast3/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Parser/parsetok.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser/parsetok.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast3/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Parser/tokenizer.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser/tokenizer.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast3/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Python/asdl.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Python/asdl.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Iast3/Include -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Python/ast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Python/ast.o
    ast3/Python/ast.c:22:1: error: conflicting types for '_PyObject_FastCall'
    _PyObject_FastCall(PyObject *func, PyObject *const *args, int nargs)
    ^
    /opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/cpython/abstract.h:145:1: note: previous definition is here
    _PyObject_FastCall(PyObject *func, PyObject *const *args, Py_ssize_t nargs)
    ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of typed-ast
  Moving to /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/typed_ast-1.4.2.dist-info/
   from /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~yped_ast-1.4.2.dist-info
  Moving to /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/typed_ast/
   from /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~yped_ast
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/nn/vspv48993vsg4vx8lyb7cccr0000gn/T/pip-install-rs4sv9b3/typed-ast_fc1729a54d824752a576842638a11041/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/nn/vspv48993vsg4vx8lyb7cccr0000gn/T/pip-install-rs4sv9b3/typed-ast_fc1729a54d824752a576842638a11041/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/nn/vspv48993vsg4vx8lyb7cccr0000gn/T/pip-record-uyxwayne/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/typed-ast Check the logs for full command output.

runfile('/Users/MJF/AAT-master/SimpleGUI.py', wdir='/Users/MJF/AAT-master')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/MJF/AAT-master/SimpleGUI.py", line 1, in <module>
    import PySimpleGUI as sg

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySimpleGUI'
```

Comment: Please add the full error message and use code formatting for it

Comment: Basically, there's no dependencies when install `PySimpleGUI`. Show your platform and python version, maybe also information about environmental, like anaconda, venv ...

Comment: Thank you for your responses, I have now added the full output and put it into code formatting.